# Pass data to php file with html template

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How I can load the file table.php with the data that I try to pass when the ajax call is made.I'm trysing with  jquery.load method the second parameter is a data array but isn't working.

This is a basic example of  that I have to make , I get this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: field in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba2\table.php on line 2
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $datos =  array(array('nombre1','apellidos1'),array('nombre2','apellidos2'));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>Tabla</h2>
        <div id="tabla">
            <table border="1px">
            <?php
                foreach ($datos as $dato) {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$dato[0]."</td><td>".$dato[1]."</td></tr>";
                }
            ?>
            </table>
        </div>

        <form id="search-form" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="search" name='search'>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
        <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.js

```
$( "#search-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/prueba2",
      data:{ action:"selection" }

    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $data = { field: $("#search").val()};
        $("#tabla").load("table.php", $data);   
    });

});
```

table.php

```
<div id="tabla">
    <?=$field?>
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>a</td><td>b</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `$field` does not exist in `table.php`. You need to use either `$_POST['field']` or `$_GET['field']` instead.

Comment: Works witn $_POST['field'] ...but I thougth that get was the default method on ajax call on jquery

Comment: GET is default for `load()`, unless you call it with object - objects get sent as POST. From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method): The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.